How can I upload an image in Cloudflare Workers and convert it to Base64?
I'm trying to replicate the functionality of a Node.js script that reads an image file and converts it to a Base64-encoded string, but I want to do this using Cloudflare Workers.
Here's the Node.js code I'm working with:
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Function to convert image to Base64
function imageToBase64(filePath) {
    // Read the image file
    const image = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    // Convert the image to Base64
    const base64Image = image.toString('base64');
    return base64Image;
}

// Replace 'your-image.jpg' with the path to your JPEG file
const imagePath = path.join(__dirname, 'apple.jpg');

// Get Base64 encoded string
const base64String = imageToBase64(imagePath);

// Output the result
console.log('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64String);

I need to achieve something similar in Cloudflare Workers, where I would like to:

Upload an image.
Read the image file.
Convert it to a Base64-encoded string.

Could someone guide me on how to accomplish this in Cloudflare Workers? I'm particularly interested in how to handle the file reading and Base64 encoding in the Workers environment.

https://walshy.dev/blog/21_09_10-handling-file-uploads-with-cloudflare-workers a combination of this and btoa should do it!
